# Pass arguments to jython script in wsadmin

Tags: python, websphere, wsadmin

I want to use `wsadmin` for CI to reload applications. For this purpose, I wrote a jython script. But I need to pass the application (e.g. `Homepage`) to the python script, so that it knows which app to restart.

I tried

```
wsadmin -lang jython -username user -password pw -f "D:\stop-app.py --name=Homepage"
wsadmin -lang jython -username user -password pw -f "D:\stop-app.py Homepage"
wsadmin -lang jython -username user -password pw -f D:\stop-app.py --name=Homepage
```

None of them works and result in an error

> WASX7011E: Cannot find file "D:\stop-app.py test"

My workaround would be the usage of environment variables. But I'm interesting why I can't call the script with arguments or what is required to do so, if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to access any additional argument via sys.argv without even adding a "--" to separate them.  The only thing that should not work is enclosing the argument inside quotes with the -f script.py.

```
wsadmin ... -f script.py a b c
wsadmin ... -f script.py  -- a b c
wsadmin ... -f script.py -- -f
```

The -- is only required if you overlap with wsadmin's own flags.